# Microsot Excel - Taking values from a sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a small question that I could not figure out in Excel. Lets assume in my sheet 1 I will import text data, now the data could have different rows but they will always have the same headings repeated every 20 rows as well as the same number of columns. In other words I duno how many sets of 20s I will have how ever I want to copy to another sheet from the 10th columns the 2nd, 5th and 10th row only.

for example if the data sheet has 20 rows I am interested in 2nd 5th and 10 row only. If sheet has 40 I am interested in 2nd, 5th, 10th & 22, 25th and 30th. If 60 --> 2nd 5th 10th & 22th 25th 30th & 42th 45th 50th. Therefore depending on the rows, the values being copied from the data would be more as every 20 rows describe the same criteria but with different values.

Thank you for your help and understanding.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a short VBA macro to achieve this.
This is how I'd solve this algorithmically, assuming the data has already been imported to the current worksheet:
1. copy the whole 'usedarea' to a VBA twodimensional array (one statement)

2. starting at row 1 (r=1), if cell in column X is empty, exit loop (recognizing the last row). You choose column X so that it is guaranteed to be non-empty for non-empty rows.
3. copy values from array[r+1,10], [r+4,10] [r+9,10] to a second 'results' array
4. r = r + 20
5. loop back to step 2
   On exit, add a new sheet and copy the results array to it in one statement.

If you're unfamiliar with copying cell areas to arrays you can directly work with cell references instead. The main point is to use a DO WHILE loop, look for a final empty cell and get the desired values by a row,column reference (e.g. via OFFSET).